# Access data in resolve in Angular 2 component

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

How to access data after resolve in Angular 2 migrated component.

I have a Angular JS app.config with routing which loads the required Angular 2 migrated component.

```
.state('users.list', {
    url: '/users/list',
    template: `<users-list></users-list>`,
    resolve: {
        users: ['users', (users) => {
            return users.get();
        }]
    }
})
```

how to access users from resolve in Angular 2 Component

Migrated Angular JS controller to Angular 2 component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'users-list',
  templateUrl: "./users-list.html",
})

export class UserListComponent {
  constructor(){}
  // I want to access 'users' here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the router `snapshot` to get the data.

```
export class UserListComponent {
  constructor(){}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.users = this.route.snapshot.data['users'];
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used `snapshot` from `ActivatedRoute`. But, it shows as undefined. I don't see any users list in route snapshot or other params